# Stored procedure in Crystal Reports 9

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crystal Reports not showing stored procedure outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577704/crystal-reports-not-showing-stored-procedure-outputs)

I created a stored procedure in SQL Server. It works fine there.

When I call it from Crystal Reports, it shows parameters fields but it does not show the outputs in database fields. Actually it shows the stored procedure in database fields but not the output fields or + sign beside the stored procedure.

Please help me do it and because I am not professional please say it step by step what should I do

Thanks

Comment: What datatypes are the columns returned by the procedure? (Crystal can have problems with very large or unusual datatypes.)

Comment: actually I made another sp for test only. It has 2 float for input parameter and three the same type for output. And it does not read any data from database for test only

Comment: Is the only output from the procedure in the form of output parameters? Crystal can only report on the results of `select` statements executed by procedures, not on output parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the results as output parameters, try including them in a `select` statement at the end of the procedure - something like:

```
select @result1, @result2, @result3
```